# Easy way to enlarge visualization in D3 (without zooming in browser)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I'd have a few different visualizations (containing primarily nodes, links and paths), which I would like to enlarge by a factor 3 without having to change the width and length of every single class. Is there a simple way in D3 to make the whole visualization bigger? I'm currently zooming in using the browser, but that is not a good solution as it requires other users to do so as well.

Comment: You can use [css transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). Then you don't even need d3. or javascript.

Comment: How? It seem to be set on an element-by-element basis?

Comment: Set the transform on the SVG.

Comment: I've added the transform to the SVG like this, but without any effect. `var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).attr("transform", "scale(3,3)");`

Comment: @felbo you can apply the css transform just once to the parent that contains all the charts. You can even apply it to body if you wanted, which would have the same effect as zooming using the browser.

Comment: @meetamit thanks that worked! I've added it as `body {transform: scale(2,2);}` However, tipsy.cs seems to malfunction as any text displayed on hover now fills the entire screen. Do you know what's wrong? My tipsy code is: `$('.node').tipsy({ gravity: 'w', html:true, title:function() { var d = this.__data__, id = d.id, inc_calls = d.inc_calls, out_calls = d.out_calls, inc_texts = d.inc_texts, out_texts = d.out_texts; return 'Incoming Calls: ' + inc_calls + '<br/>' + 'Outgoing Calls: '+ out_calls + '<br/>' + 'Incoming Texts: ' + inc_texts + '<br/>' + 'Outgoing Texts: ' + out_texts;}} );`

Comment: @felbo sorry, but I've never used tipsy.